# How to integrate Perl automation test script with TeamCity build

Tags: perl, teamcity

I have a Rest API. I wrote my test automation in Perl which sends `curl` commands. I want to integrate the tests with TeamCity build so that any change in the code will be pulled, installed in a machine and the tests will be run. If all the tests pass then only the build will be green in TeamCity.

Now I don't know how to integrate Perl with TeamCity. Is there any plugins available for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Teamcity plugin for Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~thaljef/TAP-Formatter-TeamCity-0.04/lib/TAP/Formatter/TeamCity.pm) to integrate your perl tests with Teamcity. If you use this ,

1. The test results are displayed in a nice Teamcity `Tests` tab witch a breakdown for Success, Failed and ignored tests.
2. You can go into the history of tests to know exactly when a change started breaking someone's tests.
3. You get a log info per each test which is useful for debugging when you have multiple tests.

The documentation for the plugin at the CPAN page  has good examples of how to implement this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Command Line Runner](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Command+Line) to execute a Perl script. If it returns a non-zero exit code the build will fail. See https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+Build+Steps:

> The build step status is considered failed if the build process returned a non-zero exit code and the **Fail build if build process exit code is not zero** build failure condition is enabled (see Build Failure Conditions); otherwise build step is successful.